# How to simulate the browser to login in https website using c++ based on Linux?

Tags: linux, browser, https, simulate, postdata

everybody,my goal is logging in a https website and downloading webpage using C++ background service program based on Linux.
  Detail needs is follow:
  (1)connect to "https://www.space-track.org/auth/login"
  (2)enter username and password in order to login in successful
  (3)post some formdata to this website
  (4)downloading the webpage.

Now,my method is using MFC::CInternetSession(code is follow. It is in the MS-Windows),but it's not successful. there must exist some problems in the codes. I hope you can help me solve the problem. maybe you can come up with better solutions using C++ to simulate the browser based on Linux. thank you very much！

```
Url = "https://www.space-track.org/auth/login/";

nPort = INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT;
CString strHeaders = _T("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

if (AfxParseURL(Url,dwSeviceType,strServerName,strTarget,nPort) == 0)
    return false;

CInternetSession sess;

sess.SetOption(INTERNET_OPTION_CONNECT_TIMEOUT,1000*20);
sess.EnableStatusCallback(TRUE);

CHttpConnection* pHttpConnect = sess.GetHttpConnection(strServerName,nPort);

CHttpFile* pHttpFile = pHttpConnect->OpenRequest(CHttpConnection::HTTP_VERB_POST,
    strTarget,NULL,1,NULL,NULL,INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE);


 CString strUserName = "*****";
 CString strPassword = "*****";
 CString strUserinfo;
 strUserinfo.Format(_T("identity=%s&password=%s"),strUserName,strPassword);

try
{
    BOOL bResult =pHttpFile->SendRequest(strHeaders,(LPVOID)(LPCTSTR)strUserinfo,strUserinfo.GetLength()* sizeof(TCHAR));
    //BOOL bResult =pHttpFile->SendRequest(strHeaders);
}
catch (CInternetException* pException)
{
    pException->m_dwError;
    pException->Delete();
}
pHttpFile->SetReadBufferSize(2048);
CString str;
CString strGetData;
while(pHttpFile->ReadString(strGetData))
{
    str +="\r\n";
    str +=strGetData;
}
CString fileName("index.html");
CFile file(fileName,CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeWrite);
file.Write(str,str.GetLength());
file.Close();
pHttpFile->Close();
delete pHttpFile;
pHttpConnect->Close();
delete pHttpConnect;
sess.Close();
return TRUE;
```

Comment: The sample code you posted looks very much like some C++ code one would find in an MS-Windows application. I guess your first step is to figure out which operating system you're using.

Comment: yes, you are right. I only find MFC::CInternetSession to try to meet the demand in the MS-Windows now. but my final goal is to realize it in the linux. if you can give direct suggestion about it in the Linux , it is so good. best of you. thank you.

Comment: At the same time. is it hard to simulate the browser to login in https website using C++ based on linux? what can I do for it? thank you.

Comment: The problem is that you are mixing HTTP protocol credentials and login with HTML form. While these two mechanisms are sometimes combined (on some sites when the developers care about users), in most cases this is not so. You would need to POST form data to the server, collect and then re-use cookies in order to imitate form-based login. This is not trivial even with the regular form, and very hard if form developers use counteractions like captcha or javascript.

Comment: thank you. I have tried to solve this problem on linux by using the curl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of Linux libraries that implement an HTTP client API, that can be used to implement HTTP/HTTPS requests in C or C++.

The grand-daddy of them all is W3C's own libwww:

http://www.w3.org/Library/

A more recent HTTP/HTTPS client library is libcurl:

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/

Either one of them can be used to implement an HTTP/HTTPS client in C or C++. However, in all cases, before using them you do need to have some understanding of HTTP/HTTPS protocols work; specifically HTTPS when it comes to certificate validation and verification.

Both of these libraries are fairly common, and most Linux distributions already have them packaged. You probably have one or both of them installed already.

Comment: Good, I used the curl to solve the problem this afternoon. Next, I can study the libcurl to improve myself and better to solve similar problems. Thank you very much.